# Assigning the same value twice in Erlang

Tags: erlang

Is it a kind of a small bug or made intentionally, that when I assign the same value to a variable more than once, it doesn't throw an error, but, like, assigns it again?

Here is an example:

```
X = 1,
X = 100 - 99,
X = 1,
X = list_to_integer("1"),
X = X.
```

Shouldn't it throw an error? Throwing an error could mean that some part of the code is trying to reassign the variable, and it can be just a luck that it's the same as it was before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not actually an assignment, but a match operation (the equal sign is actually the match operator). See http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/patterns.html

What actually happens is that you are trying to "pattern match" what's on the left side of the operator (=) against what's on the right side.

If there's a variable on the left side and it's not bounded yet, it will be bounded to the value you have on the right side.

On the other hand, if the variable is already bound and the value is the same as what's on the right side of the operator, nothing happens, the matching just succeeds.

If the values are different, there's a pattern matching error.

Note that the special variable "_" will always succeed when pattern matching any value.

Pattern matching in Erlang is really helpful, because you can fail fast when something's wrong. For example in this code:

```
{ok, Value} = some_function()
```

If some_function/0 returns something like {error, _} your code will just crash and you don't risk to continue execution with invalid values.

If some_function returns the expected value, the variable Value will be now be bounded to that result, it's like having an assignment and an assertion in one line of code (if you want to look at it that way).

Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, thanks. It looks like Erlang has no traditional variable assigning mechanism as I am used to see in other languages.

Comment: Great! Note that pattern matching has many uses in Erlang that I left out of the answer because you specifically asked about one use case, but you can use pattern matching in function clauses, try-catch, case, etc. Using pattern matching usually gives your code more clarity and is a great way to avoid ifs and spot bugs in the code. You can read more in this great book http://learnyousomeerlang.com/syntax-in-functions Cheers!